# How to pass a variable from a python script to flask application

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

Im trying to pass a variable from a python script to my flask application so it can be displayed on my webserver

The following is the python script (helloworldtest.py):

```
import json

variable = "Hello World"

def hello():
  return variable


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

The ajax call i am using to retrieve this data is as follows:

```
function getData()
{
    
    // FIX THIS
    $.ajax
         (
            {
            type: "get",
            url : "/static/helloworldtest.py",
            datatype: "jsonp",
            success: function(response)
                {
                    var output = response;
                    console.log(output);
                    document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = output;
                }
            }
        );

};

</script>
</head>
<body onload="startTime()">
    <h1>BioCloud Sensor</h1>
    <h2>The date and time on the server is : <span id=clock>  </span> </h2>
    <h2> The variable sent by the script is <span id=hello> </span> </h2>
</body>
```

console.log(output) is returning:

```
import json

variable = "Hello World"

def hello():
  return variable


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

how do I retrieve just the variable?

variable = "hello World"

to return and display "hello world"?

(sorry i am a new programmer if there is any additional information i need to post please let me know)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read up a bit more on the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/), especially their [Quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) page. You're trying to retrieve the entire file, but what you want to do is route the `hello` method so that its output is retrievable with ajax. The quickstart page linked above has a great "Hello World" example.